# Mule - Need to have FTP endpoint with path as variable in my Mule Requester

Tags: path, ftp, mule

I have yet one more issue that I have not been able to get resolved in my Mule Requester project.

I am trying to request files on request from an FTP server in a specified path.
The path comes in with the request, and I simply have to get files in the /Incoming/Company123 folder.  The code is here:

```
    <ftp:endpoint name="ftp_For_Requester_Json" host="${ftp.host}" port="${ftp.port}" path="#['/Incoming/' + flowVars.companyFolder]" user="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.pwd}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" connector-ref="FTPGlobalConnector"> 
        <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.json"> </file:filename-wildcard-filter>  
    </ftp:endpoint>
    <mulerequester:request-collection config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="ftp_For_Requester_Json" doc:name="Mule Requester"></mulerequester:request-collection>
```

Unfortunately, I have yet to get this working.   Is there anything wrong with the code, or is this a limitation to the endpoint or requester?  If so, is there any suggestion on how to make this to work?

UPDATE:
I have also tried the requester this way:

```
<set-variable variableName="reqesterReference" value="ftp://user:pwd@localhost#[flowVars.folderSource]" doc:name="Variable requestor reference"></set-variable>
<mulerequester:request-collection config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="#[flowVars.reqesterReference]" doc:name="Mule Requester"></mulerequester:request-collection>
```

This "appears" to work, but doesn't return any result and after the timeout period throws this exception:

> org.mule.api.MessagingException: Failed to receive event over:
>   DefaultInboundEndpoint{endpointUri=ftp://user:@localhost/Incoming/123_Folder,
>   connector=EEFtpConnector {   name=FTPGlobalConnector   lifecycle=start
>   this=4825372   numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
>   createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true   connected=true
>   supportedProtocols=[ftp]   serviceOverrides= } , 
>   name='endpoint.ftp.localhost.Incoming.123.Folder', mep=ONE_WAY,
>   properties={}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null,
>   action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false,
>   initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8,
>   disableTransportTransformer=false} (timeout=1000)
>   (org.mule.api.transport.ReceiveException). Message payload is of type:
>   NullPayload